# VBA. Data not splitting with Other parameter set to True

Tags: excel, vba

Why isn't the data getting splitted with the "-". When I try "." it works.[image]

[image]

Comment: Since you chose to post screenshots and not text, please explain to me how I can get your data and code into my workbook so I can try to replicate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is being stored as dates which is a numeric value (today's excel date is 44,885), which does not have a dash, it's just displayed that way. To prove it, change the formatting of a cell to a dollar amount. The split you're using with period is just getting the time from the date (noon would be .5).

If you're trying to split out by month and day, consider converting to text or using the month and day function.  Or you could use this function next to your original data and drag it down, and then apply your vba code to the new data (which will be text), I believe you'll get what you expect.

```
=text(A2,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM")
```

Comment: Can you show me how I would convert the column?

Comment: Just put that formula in cell b2 and drag it down. You could then copy paste values over your original, or a variety of other solutions.

Comment: Then should I run the VBA code again and on the column B now?

Comment: Yeah that'd be good.

Comment: This is what I get. I uploaded a new screenshot above in the answer. Its basically just showing me formuals

Comment: StackOverflow is not a help desk. You posted a question, to which I gave you an answer: *your data is numeric not string which is why it's not splitting as there are no dashes in the cells*.  Unless you believe this isn't correct (which it is) then the proper action is to click `accept` and it's up to you to figure out a solution. My suggestion was just trying to be helpful. I'm not sure what you did, or what Excel you're on. I would use: `=FILTER(MONTH(A:A),(ROW(A:A)>1)*(NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))))` with your original data and then repeat for day, year, hour or whatever.